# Stuck with 3D bar plot issues in Python

Tags: python

I am currently trying to use python with my data science study. I want to draw a 3D plot which has 2X2 array in my .CSV table

And I tried like this referred to every sources I saw in other websites.

Here is my code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
test="C:\\Users\\ynm20\\Desktop\\3D_Collision_Efficiency.csv"
rd=pd.read_csv(test)
kd=rd.values
ad=kd.ravel()
kd=np.reshape(ad, (6, 6))

fig = plt.figure() 
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
x = np.array([[i]*10 for i in range(6)]).ravel()
y = np.array([i for i in range(6)]*25)
z = np.zeros(6*6)
dx = np.ones(6*6)
dy = np.ones(6*6)
dz = kd.ravel()

ax1.bar3d(x, y, z, dx, dy, dz)
```

and I count with this error msg in my spyder IDE:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXEfX.png)

Sorry for my messy code, but I think python has great library compared other one I used before.

Could you help me to check where should I check and
Thanks for better code to draw a 3D bar plot with this array.

```
        1       2       3       4       6       5
0  0.0372  0.0070  0.0017  0.0011  0.0075  0.7507
1  0.0284  0.0054  0.0014  0.0009  0.0059  0.7564
2  0.0231  0.0044  0.0011  0.0007  0.0049  0.7582
3  0.0168  0.0032  0.0008  0.0005  0.0036  0.7582
4  0.0132  0.0026  0.0006  0.0004  0.0029  0.7569
5  0.0065  0.0013  0.0003  0.0002  0.0180  0.7454
```

Hopefully looks like the screenshot below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwzJy.png)

Comment: Can you provide the file?

Comment: @GabrielAvendaño for sure, but I am not sure how can I provide the file, It seems I can not revise my question adding file on it. Could you let me know how can I share .CSV file?